# no Wireless after installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, connection

I have been working on this for 3 days now. I am not an Ubuntu user by choice, but am trying to get it working on a dell latitude 1200. When it was running 9.04 wireless was fine.  I upgraded to 12.04 so that I could upgrade firefox. I have tried every possible command that I have been able to find regarding installing broadcom STA driver.  I really don't understand how I ams supposed to use a wired connection-i don't have one. My device is working, but when I do a iwconfig command I get LO no wireless extensions, and eth0 no wireless extension. There is no wlan shown.
Please explain in detail what to do.  I am not a programmer at all and don't wish to be.  HELP!

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of problems via upgrading ubuntu versions. I recommend you just do a clean install not an upgrade. It will do it correct.I had 12.04 and upgraded it to 12.10 but everything goes wrong. Now I just installed 13.04 and everything working fine.

Do it a try.